# Variable Substring Assistance

Tags: variables, batch-file, substring

Here's a snippet of my file:

```
set checkVal=0
:checkforStart
call set checkSub=%%_input:~%checkVal%,1%%
if /i %checkSub% EQU ( goto parenthesisCheck
if /i %checkSub% EQU ' goto noPar
set /a checkVal=%checkVal% + 1
goto checkforStart
:parenthesisCheck
set /a checkVal=%checkVal% + 1
set _startPar=%checkVal%
:checkforEnd
call set checkSub=%%_input:~%checkVal%,1%%
if /i %checkSub% EQU ) goto endParenthesis
if /i %checkSub% EQU ( goto parenthesisCheck
set /a checkVal=%checkVal% + 1
goto checkforEnd
:endParenthesis
set /a _endPar= %checkVal% - %_startPar%
call set parContents=%%_input=:~%_startPar%,%_endPar%%%
echo Parenthesis: %parContents%
:noPar
pause >nul
goto end
```

The problem I'm having is that when I try to return what was in the parenthesis, it returns:

```
~1,4
```

Or something along those lines, instead of the numbers or letters that are supposed to be isolated from the original input.

Thank you for any and all help.

Here is the full file, if you need it: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2lljcy5t7qme0nb/substring%20parenthesis%20finder.txt

Comment: Where you say `Or something along those lines`, is the output you're getting exactly `~1,4` or is it `%_input:~1,4%`?

Comment: @unclemeat The output I'm getting is `~1,4` because the input I give is `(test)` Would you like me to display the whole file? It is only a few lines longer.

Answer (score 3):

That is the value you will get if you attempt to do something like `set val=%var:~1,4%` when var is undefined. Substring and search/replace operations do not work properly if the variable is undefined - instead they return the instructions after the colon. This is exactly the situation you have because your final assignment has an unwanted `=` in the expression.

You have:

```
call set parContents=%%_input=:~%_startPar%,%_endPar%%%
```

So it is looking to extract a substring from a variable named `_input=`, which cannot possibly exist - user defined variable names cannot contain `=`.

Easily fixed by removing the `=`

```
call set parContents=%%_input:~%_startPar%,%_endPar%%%
```

Comment: I have linked the entire file at the bottom of the post. Everything is defined.

Comment: @Aty'ai - yes, but your variable name is wrong in the assignment, so it isn't defined! I've updated my answer.

Comment: "user defined variable names cannot contain =". `set var^==test` - `echo %var=%` - `test` ;)

Comment: @unclemeat - That creates a variable named `var` with a value of `=test`. You can try all day, but you will not succeed in creating a variable with `=` in name using pure batch.

Answer (score 0):

You should instead enable delayed expansion at the start of your script and use `!` in place of the surrounding `%` symbols.

```
setLocal enableDelayedExpansion

set checkSub=!_input:~%checkVal%,1!

set parContents=!_input=:~%_startPar%,%_endPar%!
```

Note, you set the `checkSub` variable twice, it's exactly the same both times, so I didn't include it twice. There are three lines you need to change, and one to add.

Comment: The checkSub sections work fine. The only part that misbehaves is at the end with the parContents.

Comment: Turn echo on and add a pause after the setting of parContents and see what it is setting the variable to.

Comment: The command, with echo off, is `call set parContents=%_input:~1,4%`

Comment: I see why I was originally retarded (I payed no attention to the call, and now I see how the expansion works, sorry), but I don't see why your variable is not expanding correctly. Try it with my suggested method and see if that works.

Comment: No change, unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

```dos
....
:endParenthesis
set /a _endPar= %checkVal% - %_startPar%
CALL :inpar %_startPar% %_endPar%

echo Parenthesis: %parContents%

:noPar
GOTO :EOF
:inpar
CALL set parContents=%%_input:~%1,%2%%

GOTO :eof
```

This worked for me...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that a line that used `&&` that I did not post on here was causing the problem. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: No, your original code had an unwanted `=` in the substring expansion. See my updated answer

Comment: @dbenham I updated the full file. It all works without a hitch now.